Why can't people access a shared calendar from the link I provided?
In Google Calendar, it looks like I should be able to share a calendar with a link from the calendar's settings.
But when people click the link there is an error of

You don't have access to
1e6f9dba6d2c3847bfb4e8df2b85a6e2f9d8a5e2c7b1f3a674df9c3d8b4f2a5c@group.calendar.google.com's calendar.

Shouldn't I be able to give people a link but not have the calendar public? I don't want to give people access tied to their email address email either. I simply want to give them a link that they click on and then be able to read and add events to a common calendar.

If my answer doesn't address your problem, please [edit] your question with additional details about the settings of your calendar (a screenshot of them would be useful) and also from where exactly you are copying the link that you are sharing.

'Modify Events' requires users have a Google Account
If you want people to be able to do any of add, remove, or edit events in your calendar:

They will need to have a Google account
Add their account email in the section 'Share with specific people or groups'
You will need to set their permissions to 'Make changes to events'


'View Events' requires sharing calendar publicly
If you want to allow people to view your calendar without specifying each person in the settings, you must share the calendar publicly:

Check/enable 'Make available to public' under 'Access permissions for events'

Leave the default as 'See all event details' unless you want it changed to 'See only free/busy (hide details)'

Copy the calendar sharing link you prefer:
Note: You could share both links then let users choose the one they prefer

Viewable in Google calendar by anyone with a Google account:
Copy the link provided by clicking the Get shareable link button
Viewable in a web page by anyone (no Google account needed)
Copy the link from 'Public URL to this calendar' in the 'Integrate calendar' section




Google Calendar Help Resources

Share your calendar with someone
Create & manage a public Google calendar

